# column growing unexpectedly when window is resized in MigLayout

Tags: java, swing, miglayout

Well I am quite new to MigLayout and have read about it on whitepaper and Quickstart but that was not enough.I put a panel and below that I want one panel to occupy 30% of window and other the rest of it i.e, 70%. When window is resized(maximised) the components are messing up.
The code is as follows:

```
    Mig_tmp1(){
    j=new JFrame("test");
    j.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    j.setLayout(new MigLayout("debug,fill","[70px]5[:70:250,grow]","[:100:]10[fill,grow]"));

    one=new JPanel();
    one.setBackground(Color.red);
    two=new JPanel();
    two.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
    three=new JPanel();
    three.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

    j.add(one,"wrap,span,grow");
    j.add(two,"grow");//,"w 40!");
    j.add(three,"grow");

    //j.pack();
    j.setSize(400, 600);
   j.setVisible(true); 
}
```

Comment: this issue must be solved a few times on this forum

Comment: i am a novice and people suggested miglayout and there are not much tutorials where i can learn about this layout,so please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the percentage that the component should grow in the constructor using `grow XX` where `XX` is the percentage to grow.

In your example:

```
j.setLayout(new MigLayout("debug,fill", "[grow 70, fill]5[grow 30, fill]", "[:100:]10[fill,grow]"));
```

That's assuming you want the orange panel to take 70% of the screen and the blue panel 30% of the screen at all times.

Comment: `grow 70` is different from `grow, 70%`. According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23001696/miglayout-column-constraint#answer-23028022, the former is about eagerness of ocupying the space left out of the component(will occupy 70% of the blank space between two components), while the latter `grow, 70%` means "occupy all the space which is left, and this col/row is 70% of the total width/height."